# Differentiation on an arbitrary set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

The subject of this question is differentiability of a function on an arbitrary set.

It doesn't matter if we exclude isolated points from the domain of a function. So, let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ whose every point is an accumulation  point of $X$.

For a function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a point $p\in X$, we can define $f’(p)=\lim\limits_{x\to p}\frac{f(x)-f(p)}{x-p}$.

If this limit exists at all points $p\in X$, $f$ is **differentiable**.

Two other definitions are known for the differentiability of a function on an arbitrary subset. The question is that if $f$ is differentiable in the above sense, is it differentiable in each of the following senses?

(1)$f$ is differentiable if there is an open set $U$ including $X$ and a differentiable function  $\tilde{f}:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f=\tilde{f}|X$.

(2)$f$ is differentiable is for all $x \in X$, there is an open set $U$ containing $x$ and a differentiable function  $\tilde{f}:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f|U\cap X=\tilde{f}|U\cap X$.

This is my original problem, not a homework.

Comment: This isn't a "do my homework for me" forum. Put in some effort. What have you tried, and why are you stuck?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: It seems like something is differentiable in the sense (2) if and only if it is differentiable in the sense (1). (1) obviously implies (2), but given (2) and the open set $U_x$ around each point $x \in X$ where $f,\tilde{f}$ coincide, then $U = \cup_{x\in X} U_x$ should work and there should be a unique way to well define $\tilde{f}$ so that it coincides with the respective choice on each $U_x,x \in X$.